# Sell products in iPhone app without In App Purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store

I know that similar questions exist on that site, but I must to be sure what can I do and what can't. I'd like to create a free application but with some restrictions. For example, you can download only one time per day a text for some song. If you want more, than you must buy it. I use for that In App Purchase, but I want also use another payments (credit cards, paypal etc.). If I good understand, I can't do that in the app, but can I use for that some website? I don't have to show that website in the app (but would be nice). 
Another question, If I am a registered user I can download texts without any restrictions, but I must give in the app username and password. Can I make a registration form in the app, or I can register only on the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a registration form in your app. But you definately cannot show a website with other payment methods inside your app. Apple will reject the app.

It is best to hide other payment methods from apple alltogether.

As for the free downloads part. It's allowed, apple can't stop you from giving free stuff to your customers. A login authorizing at the external website is just fine. But as long as they can't see your using other payment methods :).

Comment: So I can't put some text in the app, eg "Go to www.example.com to buy 10 texts per day"?

Comment: Depends on the situation. If the website in question does nothing more then selling content for your iPhone app it's possible that it gets rejected over that. Happened to me before. It could pass, but in my experience they reject if they don't like what they see.

If, as Dunkel stated, you also sell goods that are usuable outside of the App, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This is a company site with information and registration. I want also to add there a subsite for payment for iPhone app, because Apple get 40% of the price in In App Purchase. This is too much.

Comment: I agree. But as long as the website you want to show is purely based on avoiding the In-App purchase system you will have to find other ways to get the App approved. The simplest way (just like Dunklestern stated) is to make the goods you sell on the website also available for download and/or use outside of the App. Make it apear as if you are not just targetting iPhone devices.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I must think what to do.

Answer (score 2):

You may not able to charge for "virtual" goods without using Apple's official in-app-purchase mechanism without Apple rejecting your App.

But it is perfectly ok (even required!) if you sell real goods to your customers. The guidelines say that you may not use in-app-purchases for real goods but only for app enhancements.

So i would just redirect your users to your website for signup/payment and provide them with a username/password combination to be able to log in with the app. Other internet services like flickr are exactly doing that.