# I sell real products through my application?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I always used to in-app virtual goods or subscriptions, but my client wants to sell real products as toy art. Someone could tell me how it works?

I sell real products through my application? How would I do this using in-app or pay pal? The apple approve.

Thanks

Comment: For what its worth (before the question disappears) you can't sell physical goods through In App purchases

Comment: @PeterM While this is true, don't forget Apple accepts other payment methods for non-digital goods used outside the app.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App Store policies, not programming.

Comment: @user1763532 Yes, but Peter is talking about IAP, which cannot be used to sell physical goods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app purchase is just for the content in the app, bonus levels, virtual coins and subscribes. Of course you can sell real world items in your app, Apple accepts this kind of app, but remember you can not use Apple's in app purchase to charge users. Your must turn to other payment method, like Paypal or credit card.

Because it is something related sensitivity data (for money, you know). So maybe you have to supply your own use term and assurance to make your users trust you.

If you plan to use Paypal to implement the payment, you might want to see the [Paypal's iOS SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK).

Answer (score -1):

Apple doesn't allow selling real-world products by in-app purchases.

Here you have [guide](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf) from Apple. Check pages 3 and 6.

If it comes to the second part of the question, you can redirect a user to prepared site to finish transaction as long as it's not stuff for the app. More about this you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265290/sell-products-in-iphone-app-without-in-app-purchase).

Comment: ok but I can sell by pay pal for example? The Apple approves applications in this format?